# Unioning multiple tables together and filtering out selection based on aggregated fields.

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am creating a view that is based on multiple tables being unioned together, and I am trying to only include results that have records.  this is the code I have so far:

```
SELECT 
'001' AS ReportNumber
,'RPT001' AS ReportName
,ISNULL(SUM(1),0) AS ActiveReportCount

FROM [DBNAME].[dbo].[V_Rpt001]

UNION ALL 

SELECT 
'002' AS ReportNumber
,'RPT_002' AS ReportName
,ISNULL(SUM(1),0) AS ActiveReportCount

FROM [DBNAME].[dbo].[V_Rpt001]

WHERE SUM(1)> 0
```

This does not work as it wants it to be grouped by something, but the only other selections are literals.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM ((SELECT '001' AS ReportNumber, 'RPT001' AS ReportName, ISNULL(SUM(1),0) AS ActiveReportCount
       FROM [DBNAME].[dbo].[V_Rpt001]
      ) UNION ALL 
      (SELECT '002' AS ReportNumber, 'RPT_002' AS ReportName, ISNULL(SUM(1),0) AS ActiveReportCount
       FROM [DBNAME].[dbo].[V_Rpt001]
      )
     ) r
WHERE ActiveReportCount > 0;
```

Comment: Yes it is. Not sure why I did not see it before.  Thanks!